# VS Code - Change predictive match font colour

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was wondering if anyone knew how to change the matched font colour for the predictive text on VS code.

[image]

For instance, I want to change the teal font match colour to another colour.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's in your theme's config file.

For the "Abyss" theme and on Linux, it's located at: `/usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/theme-abyss/themes/abyss-color-theme.json`. On Windows, I'm pretty sure it's in `%AppData%`.

Search for `list.highlightForeground`. After changing it, you'll probably need to reload the window.

Documentation:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_lists-and-trees

> `list.highlightForeground`: List/Tree foreground color of the match highlights when searching inside the list/tree.

Comment: You can change that setting in your  "workbench.colorCustomizations" settings as well.

Comment: @Mark Didn't know about that, that's great.